# How to check which day of the week I have selected and it is weekend or not

Tags: java, android

I have the written the code in the datepicker. It is working properly. Now I want to add one feature. It is whether it is weekday or weekend. I want some guideline that which method required to use to check which date I have selected and also either it is weekend or weekday. Please, any one can check my code and guide me. It will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class DateTimePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
       TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener


      // TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
    //Declaration for class
    ButtonViews views;
    dpListener dpListenerView;
    // Declartion for member vairables
    int day, month, x_year;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    Calendar calendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        views = new ButtonViews();
        dpListenerView = new dpListener();

        //ButtonListener
        views.button_date.setOnClickListener(this);
        views.button_time.setOnClickListener(this);
        //

       // pick up the default date using Calender class
         calendar =  GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.getDefault());

        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        x_year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        setupDate(day, month, x_year);
        setupTime(hour, minute);
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_date:
                showDatePickerDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.button_time:
                  showTimePickerDialog();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void setupTime(int hours, int minutes) {
        views.button_time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes);
    }

    private void setupDate(int day, int month, int year) {

        String strMonth = ((month + 1) <= 9) ? ("0" + (month + 1)) : String.valueOf(month + 1);
                  views.button_date.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + strMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog
                (
                        this,
                         dpListenerView,
                       /* new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            } },*/
                        //this,

                        x_year,
                        month,
                        day
                );

           datepickerdialog.show();
    }


 /*   private OnDateSetListener dpListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
               *//* day = dayOfMonth;
                month = monthOfYear;
                x_year = year;*//*
                setupDate(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear,year);
            }

        };*/


    public void showTimePickerDialog() {

      TimePickerDialog   timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                DateTimePickerActivity.this,
                this,
                hour,
                minute,
                true
         );


        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
//        setupDate(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear,year);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setupTime(hourOfDay, minute);
    }


   class ButtonViews {

        Button button_time;
        Button button_date;

        public ButtonViews() {
            button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
            button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        }
    }

  class dpListener implements OnDateSetListener
  {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                day = dayOfMonth;
                month = monthOfYear;
                x_year = year;

            int i = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(DateTimePickerActivity.this
                            , "You have selected " + calendar.SUNDAY
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;

                default:
                    setupDate(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear,year);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
Calendar yourCalendar;

int dayOfWeek = yourCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // it will returns 1 (Calendar.SUNDAY) to 7 (Calendar.SATURDAY)
```

Then you should check

```
If(dayOfWeek == 7 || dayOfWeek == 1){
  // as your requirement: you should display mesage they can not select the weekend" here
  // then you set the value in datepickerdialog by current date
  return "weekend";
}else{
  return "week date";
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend for the reply. I would like to stop the user selecting the date as well if weekend is selected else it should show the date. Please, could you help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know why you want to stop the user selecting the date as well. Please explain more details. Thanks

Comment: If they select weekend then it should display the current date along with the message as "they can not select the weekend" and not the selected weekend date. It is the application requirement ( All government warehouse are closed for that reason)

Comment: Hi Friend,  Please, guide me where can I find update?

Comment: @J.Vyas sorry for late response. but if you see my answer solve your problem (in the question title) please mark it as correct answer, it will help me and also help another person come to this post. thank you very much